# Пытался руками дописать YOLOv3 в качестве тренировки, но на препроцессинге изображения ловлю invalid syntax

Tags: машинное-обучение, информатика

```
#Функция предобработки и фильтрации предограничивающих рамок и объектов
#pred_bbox - массив необработанных ограничивающих рамок после предсказания 
#original_image - оригинальное изображение 
#input_size - размер входной сети
#score_treshold - порог фильрации объектов с низкой вероятностью
def postprocessing_boxex(pred_bbox, original_image, input_size, score_treshold):
  #преобразование тензора в массив numpy
  pred_bbox = np.array(pred_bbox)
  #разделяем массив по значениям
  #координаты центра, длина и ширина ограничивающей рамки
  pred_xywh = pred_bbox[:, 0:4]
  #показатель уверенности того, что в ограничивающей рамки есть объект
  pred_conf = pred_bbox[:, 4]
  #вероятности присутствия в рамке каждого конкретного класса
  pred_prob = pred_bbox[:, 5:]
  #изменяем формат ограничивающих рамок
  #(x,y,w,h) -> (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax)
  #xmin = x - w/2, ymin = y-h/2, xmax = x + w/2, ymax = y + h/2
  pred_coor = np.concatenate(pred_xywh[:, :2] - pred_xywh[:, 2:]*0.5, pred_xywh[:, :2] + pred_xywh[:, 2:] * 0.5)
  #сеть масштабирует размеры ограничивающих рамок относительно  своего входа 416х416
  #нам нужно масштабировать размеры ограничивающих рамок относительно изначального размера оригинального изображения
  #(xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax) -> (xmin_org, ymin_org, xmax_org, ymax_org)
  #то есть производим изменения обратные функции image_preprocessing
  #исхожные размеры оригинального изображения 
  org_h, org_w = original_image.shape[:2]
  #масштабы изменения размера
  resize_ratio = min(input_size / org_w, input_size / org_h)
  #вычисляем, насколько было сдвинуто изображение по осям х и у
  dw = (input_size - resize_ratio * org_w) / 2
  dh = (input_size - resize_ratio * org_h) / 2
  #масштабируем значения по ох и оу и убираем сдвиг
  pred_coor[:, 0::2] = (pred_coor[:, 0::2] - dw) / resize_ratio
  pred_coor[:, 1::2] = (pred_coor[:, 1::2] - dh) / resize_ratio
  #ограничиваем значения рамок, которые вышли за пределы картинки
  pred_coor = np.concatenate(np.maximum(pred_coor[:, :2], [0, 0]), np.maximum(pred_coor[:, 2:], [org_2 - 1, org_h - 1]))
  #задаем маску неправильных ограничивающих рамок
  #условие xmin>xmax or ymin>ymax
  invalid_mask = np.logical_or((pred_coor[:, 0] > pred_coor[:, 2]), (pred_coor[:, 1] > pred_coor[:, 3]))
  #присваиваем 0 всему что попадает под условия маски
  pred_coor[invalid_mask] = 0
  #диапазон масштаба рамок
  valid_scale = [0, np.inf]
  #вычисление масштаба каждой ограничивающей рамки
  bboxes_scale = np.sqrt(np.multiply.reduce(pred_coor[:, 2:4] - pred_coor[:, 0:2], axis = -1)
  #создание маски с условием для того, чтобы масштаб рамки был в допустимом диапазоне
  scale_mask = np.logical_and((valid_scale[0] < bboxes_scale), (bboxes_scale < valid_scale[1]))
  # Находим класс объекта в каждой ограничивающей рамке.
  # 80 one hot encoding - > 1 index.
  classes = np.argmax(pred_prob, axis=-1)
  #вычисляем итоговую вероятность, умножая итоговую уверенность на вероятность класса, который имеет максимальную вероятность в данной рамке
  scores = pred_conf * pred_prob[np.arange(len(pred_coor)), classes]
  #маска по вероятности с условием, чтобы значение было выше допустимого порога
  score_mask = scores > score_treshold
  #общая маска по вероятности и масштабу
  mask = np.logical_and(scale_mask, score_mask)
  #выкидываем недопустимые рамки по условию маски
  coors, scores, classes = pred_coors[mask], scores[masc], classes[mask]
  #объединяем в один массив и возвращаем
  return np.concatenate([coors, scores[:, np.newaxis], classes[:, np.newaxis]], axis=-1)
```

**На строке со scale_mask, где пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы маска была в допустимом диапазоне, ловлю invalid syntax. Ошибку не понимаю от слова совсем.**

```
File "<ipython-input-19-d23cd7bb7dcf>", line 46
    scale_mask = np.logical_and((valid_scale[0] < bboxes_scale), (bboxes_scale < valid_scale[1]))
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**Ошибка выглядит так. Извините за некорректность, в первый раз пишу на SO**

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Пишите всё на русском, это русский раздел SO

Comment: И текст ошибки приведите прямо в вопросе, по возможности целиком. Без данных для воспроизведения ошибки нам тут остаётся только гадать, что за ошибка.

Comment: Исправил, теперь выглядит терпимо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
File "<ipython-input-19-d23cd7bb7dcf>", line 46
    scale_mask = np.logical_and((valid_scale[0] < bboxes_scale), (bboxes_scale < valid_scale[1]))
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Как обычно в таких случаях, когда вдруг ругается на самое начало явно корректной в этом месте строки ошибку нужно искать в незакрытых кавычках или скобках в предыдущей строке или строках. И правда в предыдущей строке кода не закрыта последняя круглая скобка, если внимательно посмотреть:

```
bboxes_scale = np.sqrt(
    np.multiply.reduce(pred_coor[:, 2:4] -
                       pred_coor[:, 0:2], axis = -1)
                                                  ^^^
```